# Best way to allow postback on a gridview without viewstate

Tags: asp.net, gridview, postback, viewstate

My gridview is basically a hit list of results from which the user selects one, and I want to get a postback saying which one he has selected. There is no need for the grid contents to survive the postback round-trip because the hit list disappears as soon as he has selected an item.

I don't want to use viewstate because the hit list is likely to be large. I don't want to databind from the database in PageLoad to repopulate the grid because the search may take a while.

what I'm thinking at the moment is that I can put some javascript on the 'select' link to store the ID of the selected item in a hidden field and then call __doPostBack

this still seems a bit clunky. can you think of a cleaner way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the postback should be triggered when the user clicks the anywhere in the row, use the `ItemDataBound` event to attach a client `onclick` handler:

```
protected void GridView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var dataItem = e.Item as GridViewRow;
    if (dataItem != null)
    {
        dataItem.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("__doPostBack(this, '{0}')", e.Row.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's basically what I have done. Actually I just added an onclick handler to the linkbutton not the whole row, and in the event argument I put the ID of the item.

I found I had to detect it by looking at the __EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT in the Page_Load but still it's worked fine and seems as elegant as anything else I can think of. I'm surprised they didn't build in a way to do this a bit more easily as it would seem to be quite a common requirement

Answer (score 0):

Is the ID of the selected item something sensitive that should not be seen by the user?

If it is not, you could just make your select button a link to the next page, with the ID as a querystring variable. Clicking would just move to the next page, no postback required.

Comment: it needs to be a postback to the same page. there are lots of other controls and things on the screen that need viewstate so I can't just use a 'get'